# C# System.IndexOutOfRangeException Error

Tags: c#, error-handling

Ok so i'm currently building a project where you import a list of proxy's but for some reason I'm getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException Error which is really bugging me now.

So here is the code it's showing on.

```
        private void LoadProxies()
    {
        accChecker.Proxies.Clear();

        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            ofd.Title = "Choose a file containing a list of proxies...";
            ofd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    if (line.Contains(":"))
                    {
                        String[] data = line.Split(':');

                        if (!Properties.Settings.Default.ProxiesLogin)
                            accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1]);
                        else
                            accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
                    }
                }
                loadProxiesBtn.Text = String.Format("Load Proxies ({0})", accChecker.Proxies.Count);

                if (accChecker.Accounts.Count > 0 && (accChecker.Proxies.Count > 0 || !loadProxiesBtn.Visible))
                    checkBtn.Enabled = true;
                else
                    checkBtn.Enabled = false;

                UpdateInfos(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

When continue is clicked it then closes the application. I'm not sure if it's a form of my code?

Comment: Did you debug it? If not, this is the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Yeah this is how I know I'm getting the error I guess "/

Comment: So which line do you get the error? what are the values of the variables in that line? If you are indexing an array with a constant, does it actually *have* that many entries?

Comment: Here is an image of the exact error I'm getting. http://i.imgur.com/zDyNEIX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem persists with following code set [With reference to attached [picture]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee2l4.png)

```
if (line.Contains(":"))
{
   String[] data = line.Split(':');

     if (!Properties.Settings.Default.ProxiesLogin)
        accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1]);
     else
         accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]); // HERE
 }
```

Here you do not know whethere your string array actually contains `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` or `data[3]` positions. More about [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Solution :

Check your array's `Length` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to verify you have data in these potions

So something like

```
 if (!Properties.Settings.Default.ProxiesLogin){
       if(data.Length > 1){
          accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1]);
       }
   }
   else{
       if(data.Length > 3){
         accChecker.QueueProxy(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
       }
   }
```

This won't solve your application logic. You will have to implement some logic to face this Length condition fails. something like `UpdateInfos(false);` [Thinking that's what you expect from this function]

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this, don't understand much do you have skype or ICQ perhaps?

Comment: you could solve the problem with the help provided :)

Comment: hmm oke that resolves the error, but then it's not loading the actual proxy list into the program.

Comment: Refer the updated answer :)  You need to handle that case since your parameters do not match the required conditions

Comment: I've tried still no luck into getting the program to load the proxy file to then send requests to the site the program is made for. If you have skype or ICQ I can show you or explain more indepth.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of data result.

```
  String[] data = line.Split(':');
```